# Using UTCTime with Hamlet

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I am using Yesod on my first site and I have a list of news items:

```
NewsItem
    date    UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    title   String
    content String
    author  String
```

which are retrieved in my handler:

```
newsitems <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc NewsItemDate]
```

and ultimately used in my template:

```
$if null newsitems
    <p>No news.
$else
    $forall Entity id entry <- newsitems
        <article>
            <h4>#{newsItemDate entry}
            <p>#{newsItemContent entry}
```

But I get an error about datatypes:

```
Handler/Home.hs:20:11:
    No instance for (Text.Blaze.ToMarkup
                       time-1.4:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime)
      arising from a use of `toHtml'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Text.Blaze.ToMarkup time-1.4:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime)
    In the first argument of `toWidget', namely
      `toHtml (newsItemDate entry_a6ev)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      toWidget (toHtml (newsItemDate entry_a6ev))
    In the expression:
      do { toWidget
             ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . Data.Text.pack)
                "<article><h4>");
           toWidget (toHtml (newsItemDate entry_a6ev));
           toWidget
             ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . Data.Text.pack)
                "</h4>\
                \<p>");
           toWidget (toHtml (newsItemContent entry_a6ev));
           .... }
```

So I figure I would go ahead and add to my Import.hs:

```
import Data.Time (UTCTime)
import Data.Time.Format (formatTime)
import Text.Blaze (ToMarkup, toMarkup)
import Text.Blaze.Internal (string)
import System.Locale (defaultTimeLocale)

-- format date as     26 July 2012
instance ToMarkup UTCTime where
   toMarkup a = string (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%e %B %Y" a)
```

Which does compile, but gives me an error at runtime in the browser:

```
Internal Server Error
PersistMarshalError "Expected UTCTime, received PersistText \"2012-08-30\""
```

So I am not sure how to solve this, any ideas?

EDIT: Source code to the site in case it is needed or curious: https://github.com/iaefai/socrsite

Comment: That package version number makes me suspicious. How many versions of `time` do you have installed? What does `ghc-pkg list time` say?

Comment: $ ghc-pkg list time
        /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.4.1-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.1/package.conf.d
           time-1.4
        /Users/drakej/.ghc/i386-darwin-7.4.1/package.conf.d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without investigating the actual error, I think your approach is not great. You will very likely eventually want several ways of formatting a `UTCTime`, after all, the type is there to store times, not just dates. By giving a `ToMarkup UTCTime` instance, you fix this globally.

I would recommend to write functions `renderAsDate :: UTCDate -> HTML`, `renderAsTime :: UTCDate -> HTML` etc. and use them in your template, e.g. `#{renderAsDate (newsItemDate entry)}`.

But this won’t solve the runtime error, which comes from the serialization layer and is likely independent of your templates.

Comment: Could my runtime issue be caused by using SQLite?

I found that if I changed my model to String or Text it worked, which makes sense for SQLite, however that said I do plan to use Postgres or something of that nature eventually.

Comment: It seems that the data base layer returns a `PersistText`. Are your columns in your database typed? What is the type of the date column? Maybe you generated it as `String` and only later changed the code to use `UTCDate`?

Comment: It was UTCDate from the beginning, however SQLite is generally untyped , but it does keep a record of the types you specify AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I am going to migrate over to a postgres database tonight I think so I can have something closer to a real deployment. While not really a solution in my current circumstance, I think you provided the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you could just use show in the hamlet? That's atleast what I've done...

```
#{show $ newsItemDate entry}
```

I've run into this instance thing before, and as this guy describes here it's something like this:

> As part of this philosophy of frugality of expression Haskell doesn’t
>   require type signatures — although an experienced Haskeller provides
>   them for clarity — so type errors in this strongly typed language are
>   often cryptic for the uninitiated. For instance, if you define a
>   function f that adds two numbers and then call it with two strings,
>   the compiler will not complain about bad arguments, it will complain
>   about string not supporting operator plus. And it will formulate this
>   complaint in a very non-obvious way.
>   [1] Under "1. Haskell is Terse"...

[1] http://fpcomplete.com/ten-things-you-should-know-about-haskell-syntax/