# Using UTCTime with SQLite in Yesod

Tags: sqlite, haskell, yesod

While using a `UTCTime` field in my model in Yesod, I get the following error:

```
PersistMarshalError "field timestamp: Expected UTCTime, received PersistText \"09:18:07\""
```

I am using SQLite to store my database. My model looks as follows:

```
Myobject
    timestamp UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    otherfield Text
```

Note that this error occurs both with and without the default value.

I am selecting the list of `Myobject`-entities as follows:

```
myobjects <- selectList [] [Desc MyobjectTimestamp]
```

Using `MyobjectOtherfield` instead of `MyobjectTimestamp` does not help either, which makes sense since all data is fetched and therefore marshaled anyway.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275273/using-utctime-with-hamlet), but the answer did not help me.

How can I use `UTCTime` in Yesod while using SQLite?

Edit:
The `PersistText \"09:18:07\"` that is mentioned in the error is the value the field defaulted to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You stored a Text value `"09:18:07"`, while it expected a UTCTime value. Did you insert values by hand?

`getCurrentTime` from `Data.Time` returns a value of type `IO UTCTime`, so you can either use `putStr getCurrentTime` in GHCI to get a valid representation, or use `now <- liftIO getCurrentTime` in your function.

EDIT:
Because `getCurrentTime` returns a timestamp like: `2013-10-25 10:16:32.1627238 UTC`, inserting a value like that in your database should resolve the error.

Comment: No, that value was inserted as a default. Where would I put that function then? Can I change the way the marshaling is done?

Comment: As for a default value, I don't know. What I do know is that a value in timestamp should look like: `2013-10-25 10:16:32.1627238 UTC` to be accepted by Yesod as a UTCTime value.
You should refer to SQLite's docs for a timestamp like that.

Comment: When I enter the date in that format, it indeed works, thanks! Include it in your answer and I'll accept yours if nobody comes with an explanation why the default does not work.

Comment: I found a solution for the default too. Using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_TIME` resolves the problem.