# Yesod: How to give UTCTime a toMarkup instance?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have this Haskell Data in the models:

```
Vocabulary json
    word Text
    date UTCTime
    deriving Show
```

I get errors with the following code:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    wordList <- runDB $ selectList [] [] :: HandlerT App IO [Entity Vocabulary]
    defaultLayout $ do
      setTitle "test"
      [whamlet|
              <ul>
                $forall Entity wordid worditem <- wordList
                  <li>#{vocabularyDate worditem} 
      |]
```

Error is:

```
 Could not deduce (blaze-markup-0.7.1.1:Text.Blaze.
ToMarkup
                          UTCTime)
        arising from a use of ‘toHtml’
      from the context: PersistEntity Vocabulary
```

I read from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275273/using-utctime-with-hamlet) that I should declare UTCTime to be an instance of ToMarkup. How and in which file should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like

```
import Data.Time.Format

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
wordList <- runDB $ selectList [] [] :: HandlerT App IO [Entity Vocabulary]
defaultLayout $ do
  setTitle "test"
  [whamlet|
          <ul>
            $forall Entity wordid worditem <- wordList
              <li>#{dateFormat $ vocabularyDate worditem} 
  |]

dateFormat :: UTCTime -> String
dateFormat = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%F"
```

I am not quite familiar with hamlet templates, so you might need to tweak this code a bit.